# echo $_SESSION then unset

Tags: php, session

I know this is an amateurish question but I need to echo a session variable then destroy the variable.

I've tried this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['m'])){
   echo($_SESSION['m']);
   unset($_SESSION['m']);
}
```

I've also tried session_destroy();

and i've tried to unset/destroy the session at the end of the page (after closing HTML tag)

The problem i'm having is the session is being destroyed before it is echoed. I've use the code above before without any problems. Is there anyway to do what I need to do, or do I have to find a different solution?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: pardon if this is allready covered, but does your 'if' fire? If you for instace forgot to call `session_start()`, it wouldn't have been set at all.

Comment: ye sorry forgot to add, i've definitely included session_start(). It also echoes fine if I dont include unset() or session_destroy()

Comment: to add to @Nanne's question: Do you have an echo when you don't unset the session? - Oops, just see your answer

Comment: Are you sure that variable even exists?

Comment: yup..
`$_SESSION['m'] = "<div id=\"contact_success\"><strong>Thank you for your message!</div>";`

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Your example works on 5.3.4

Comment: Have you tried var_dump($_SESSION)?

Comment: ok guys, I think theres an underlying problem here that I need to investigate. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: I don't want to be picky here and I don't think it causes your problem ... but who knows. Your value is missing the strong closing tag.

Answer (score 16):

I know it's a bit late but recently I encountered this problem and I'll answer it for anyone who needs it.

I'm pretty sure you did a redirection using the `header` method to the same page that did the `unset` of the session. Something along these lines:

```
<?php
    if(condition)
        $_SESSION = "foo";
    header("Location: $self");
?>
<html>
    ...
    <?php echo $_SESSION["foo"]; unset($_SESSION["foo"]); ?>
    ...
```

The problem with `header` is that it doesn't stop the execution of the script (as it seems) and therefore the script continued to execute and unset the session.

The solution is to add `exit(0)` (or any flag you may need) after the header redirection, like this:

```
<?php
    if(condition)
        $_SESSION = "foo";
    header("Location: $self");
    exit(0);
?>
```

It's indeed a very obscure problem and a time consuming one as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you out a little, or atleast set you in the right direction. Try throwing each action into its own if statement.

```
if ((isset($_SESSION['m']))) {
echo $_SESSION['m'];
}
if ((isset($_SESSION['m']))) {
unset($_SESSION['m']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['m'])){
   $sessionVar = $_SESSION['m'];
   unset($_SESSION['m']);

   echo $sessionVar;
}
```

Comment: nope, still no luck. I think the problem is the session is being unset before anything else. So the session is being unset before `$sessionVar` is set

Answer (score 0):

Use this maybe it works :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['m'])){
   echo($_SESSION['m']);
   str_pad(' ',4096);
   flush();
   sleep(1); // You can remove this line 
   unset($_SESSION['m']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $_SESSION is a reference, so when you copy it (or some offset within it), you're actually copying a reference. i.e:

```
$a = $_SESSION['a'];
```

is copying the pointer value of $_SESSION['a'] to $a so they point to the same place in memory. So when you unset $_SESSION['a'], you're removing the data pointed to by $a. This is why $a seems to disappear in your echo.

This answer doesn't solve the problem, or course, but it at least explains what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

type this above the < html > tag.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['m']))
      $_SESSION['m']=$_SESSION['m']+1;
 else
      $_SESSION['m']=1;
 echo "Session = ". $_SESSION['m'];
 ?>
```

and type this below < /html > tag

```
 <?php

      if(isset($_SESSION['m']))
          unset($_SESSION['m']);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem again, and I always seem to solve it in different ways. This time, I decided to go with a combination of php, jquery, and ajax.

```
<script>
var message = '<?php echo $_SESSION['message'];?>';
$(document).ready(function(){
if (message != ''){
alert(message);
$('#dump').load("http://{your absolute path here}/killthemessenger.php");   
}
});
</script>
<div class="hidden" id="dump" >This Should Be Hidden With CSS</div>
```

This script is on my navigation menu, which is included on every page, so I can send a message to any page the user is on easily. It loads the session message into a javascript var, then alerts the user and then loads a php page into the hidden "dump" div, that just unsets the session message so it doesn't alert any more than once.

killthemessenger.php

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['message']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ben's answer didn't quite work for me. For whatever reason my `exit()` was still firing after the `close()`.

It's not pretty but I got it working with:

```
if(condition) {
    $_SESSION["foo"] = "print this";
    $_SESSION["bar"] = 1;
    header("Location: $self");
}
<html>
...
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["foo"])){
    echo($_SESSION["foo"]);
    $_SESSION["bar"] += 1;
    if($_SESSION["bar"] >=3) {
        unset($_SESSION["foo"]);
        unset($_SESSION["bar"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to use die(); after header redirection.

```
header("Location: index.php");
die();
```